# The Complex Logarithm of a Function

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

For an analytic function $f$ that does not vanish on a simply connected region, we may define its logarithm to be the function:

$$\log f=g(z):=\int_{y}\frac{f'}{f}dz+c_0.$$

Where $\gamma$ is some path starting at an arbitrary point in the region, and ending at $z$; while $c_0$ satisfies $e^{c_0}=f(z_0)$.

I believe that this logarithm should satisfy under certain conditions that: $$\log f=\log |f|+iarg(f).$$

Am I right, or this is too difficult in general?

Comment: $\gamma$ should start at $z_0,$ I believe.

Comment: Depending on how you choose $c_0$, I believe you can only get $\log f = \log |f| + i(\operatorname{arg}(f)+2\pi k)$ for integers $k.$

Comment: there is a bit of confusion here when you talk about $\arg$ in the sense that for each $z$, the equation $\log f(z)=\log |f(z)|+ i\arg(f(z))$ picks a value from the infinite set $Arg (c)$, where $c=f(z)$ in a consistent way that makes the function $\arg f(z)=\Im{\log f(z)}$ harmonic (also continuos, real analytic etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g$ satisfies $g' = \frac{f'}{f}$ in the given domain, so that
$$
 (f e^{-g} )' = f' e^{-g} - f g' e^{-g} = 0 \\
\implies f e^{-g} = \text{const} = f(z_0) e^{-g(z_0)} = f(z_0) e^{-c_0} = 1 \, .
$$
Therefore $e^g = f$, i.e. $g$ is “a holomorphic logarithm” of $f$  in the domain. In particular 
$$
 f(z) = e^{g(z)} = e^{\operatorname{Re} g(z)} e^{ i \operatorname{Im}g(z)}
$$
which implies that 
$$
 |f(z)| = e^{\operatorname{Re}g(z)} \implies \operatorname{Re}g(z) = \log |f(z)|
$$
and that $ \operatorname{Im}g(z)$ is *an argument* of $f(z)$. So
$$
 g(z) = \log |f(z)| + i \operatorname{arg}f(z)
$$
in the sense that $\operatorname{arg}f(z)$ is a continuous function which is an argument of $f(z)$ for each $z$.